# Plotly Python heatmap colorbar orientation

Tags: python, plotly, heatmap, colorbar

Is there a way to change the orientation of the colorbar in Plotly heatmap? Setting the orientation in the layout does not do anything:

```py
go.Layout(
    legend=dict(
    orientation="h")
)
```

It doesn't even give me an error message. I have also tried change the orientation in the colorbar directly:

```
colorbar = dict(
    orientation="h"
                   )
```

but I get the error message that 'orientation' is not a valid property of 'plotly.graph_objs.heatmap.ColorBar'.

I know how to set the position of the colorbar and I have looked the valid properties of the colorbar but could not find a way to set its orientation. Is this possible?

Comment: So you'd like to rotate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe so. According to [this open issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/1244) and the response from Chriddyp (co-founder of Plotly), a horizontal colorbar has not been implemented but this feature may be added in future releases of Plotly.

If you really need it— I suppose you can try to draw the colorbar yourself using annotations but that's admittedly a lot of work.

Comment: FYI: Just figured out that this is available in the current version 5.10.0 (I believe it was added in 5.5.0).

Comment: @drlee oh awesome- thanks for circling back here

Answer (score 3):

**Set the orientation of the colorbar.**

As per the Plotly [Documentation](https://plotly.com/python/reference/#heatmap-colorbar):

```
# For the vertical orintation
fig.update_traces(colorbar_orientation='v', selector=dict(type='heatmap'))

# For the horizontal orintation
fig.update_traces(colorbar_orientation='h', selector=dict(type='heatmap'))
```

Default: "v" #vertical